# Urho.Forms Transparent Background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, urhosharp, urho3d

Using a Urho.Forms UrhoSurface View in a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage, is it possible to make the background texture on the UrhoSurface View transparent so that the ContentPage contents shows through? i.e. Overlay the UrhoSurface on the ContentPage content? If so, does anyone have a hint or an example how to accomplish?

Thank you in advance :)